# Cloud Gaming on a Virtual Machine on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine

On any cloud platform specifically can we run a windows VM and install a windows game ??
Will this work and will the data be lost after we disconnect the instance and is it feasible.

Answer (score 2):

If you make sure to attach a persistent disk to the machine, then you can install games on it and they will stay there. Also make sure you get a machine with a GPU! You would probably have pretty bad experience using Remote Desktop though. Apart from that, this is entirely feasible.

Comment: So how do I add a persistent Disk on a GCP and is this all available on the free tier of the gcp

Comment: You can find all that stuff in de GCP docs (for example: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/regional-persistent-disk). Here's some info on the free tiers: https://cloud.google.com/free.